# Combine list of numbers to get maximum amount of sums within a given limit

Tags: c#

Lets say you have a list of numbers which are all below 10 - e.g.{7, 6, 5, 4}
The goal is to combine them into a sum >= 10 and I want to achieve the highest number of combinations without reusing any numbers. Also, if possible, the solutions should be as close as possible to 10.

E.g.
7+4 & 6+5 = 2 solutions (11 & 11 - max distance to 10 is 1)
7+5 & 6+4 = 2 solutions (12 & 10 - max distance to 10 is 2)
7+6 = 1 solution (since the remaining 5+4 < 10)

My first approach was to take the highest number and then add the lowest number. If this didn't equal or exceed the limit, then I would add the next lowest number.
It resulted in this code:

```
        IList<int> numbers = new List<int>{6, 4, 2, 2, 5, 2};
        var numbersOrdered = numbers.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
        var resultList= new List<List<int>>();

        int highIndex = 0;
        int lowIndex = numbersOrdered.Count() - 1;

        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        result.Add(numbersOrdered[highIndex]);
        int sum = numbersOrdered[highIndex];

        while (highIndex < lowIndex)
        {
            sum += numbersOrdered[lowIndex]; 
            result.Add(numbersOrdered[lowIndex]);
            if (sum >= 10)
            {
                //Found valid combination - add to result list
                resultList.Add(result);

                //Move index pointers
                highIndex++;
                lowIndex--;

                //Reset temporary result list
                result = new List<int>();
                result.Add(numbersOrdered[highIndex]);
                sum = numbersOrdered[highIndex];
            }
            else
            {
                //Didn't find valid combination. Try to add the next lowest number
                lowIndex--;
            }
        }
```

It did, however, quickly turn out to be the wrong approach. Therefore I'm currently trying with this approach which seems more solid, but still have a minor issue.

```
private void FindBestMatches(List<int> numbersOrdered, List<List<int>> resultList)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var bestMatch = new List<int>();
            var combinations = GetPowerSet(numbersOrdered);
            foreach (var combination in combinations)
            {
                int sum = combination.Sum();
                if (sum == 10) //Found perfect match - use this combination
                {
                    bestMatch = combination.ToList();
                    break;
                }
                else if (sum > 10 && (!bestMatch.Any() || sum < bestMatch.Sum()))
                {
                    bestMatch = combination.ToList();
                }
            }
            //If we found a valid solution, remove these values from the ordered list
            if (bestMatch.Any())
            {
                AddCombinationToResults(bestMatch, numbersOrdered, resultList);
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    private static void AddCombinationToResults(IEnumerable<int> combination, List<int> numbersOrdered, List<List<int>> resultList)
    {
        //Remove the numbers in the result from the ordered numbers list
        combination.ForEach(item => numbersOrdered.Remove(item));
        //Add the result to the list of pools
        resultList.Add(combination.ToList());
    }

    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSet<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
               select
                   from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
                   where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
                   select list[i];
    }
```

When using this approach it seems that I get the right number of solutions, but they aren't optimized - e.g. with {7,6,5,4} I get {6, 4} and {7, 5} instead of {7, 4} and {6, 5}, which is obvious, since I look for the smallest sum. But I can't figure out an approach that finds 11 and 11 instead of 10 and 12?

Comment: Brute force recursion, brute force iteratation and if you have the bones a genetic algorithm are all on the table. Question is too broad, but a viable first try would be to generate a list of all possible permuations, (1, 2,3 & 4) numbers and then sum them to see if they fit. Then you can start getting clever and skip the permutations that will never work such as all sequences of 1 number as you have no number in there >=10.  Opportunities fall recursion will fall out of doing this. e.g. Permuations([7],[6,5,4]) Permutations ([7,6], [5,4]) etc.

Comment: Personally I never start with recursion unless I can describe the function before I start, and I'll avoid it if practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error I've come up with this solution. It's not perfect or quick, but it will do in my case.

```
    private List<List<decimal>> FindBestMatches(List<decimal> numbersOrdered)
    {
        var resultList = new List<List<decimal>>();

        if (numbersOrdered.Sum() < 10)
        {
            return resultList;
        }

        var possibleSumsWithinRange = GetPowerSet(numbersOrdered).Select(combination => combination.Sum()).Distinct().Where(sum => sum>= 10 && sum < 20).OrderBy(sum => sum);
        //Remove highest sum if there are more than one possible sum
        if (possibleSumsWithinRange.Count() > 1)
        {
            possibleSumsWithinRange.ToList().RemoveAt(possibleSumsWithinRange.Count() - 1);   
        }

        //Go through all possible sums in order to find best result (lowest highest sum)
        foreach (var possibleSum in possibleSumsWithinRange)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Sum:" + possibleSum);
            var subResultList = new List<List<decimal>>();
            var numbers = numbersOrdered.ToList();
            while (true)
            {
                var combinations = GetPowerSet(numbers);
                var bestMatch = new List<decimal>();
                foreach (var combination in combinations)
                {
                    decimal sum = combination.Sum();
                    if (sum < possibleSum)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (sum == possibleSum) //Found perfect match - use this combination
                    {
                        bestMatch = combination.ToList();
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (sum > possibleSum && (!bestMatch.Any() || sum < bestMatch.Sum()))
                    {
                        bestMatch = combination.ToList();
                    }
                }
                //If we found a valid solution, remove these values from the ordered list and use same approach on the remaining values
                if (bestMatch.Any())
                {
                    bestMatch.ForEach(item => numbers.Remove(item));
                    subResultList.Add(bestMatch.ToList());
                    continue;
                }
                //If the new solution is the first or better than the previous, then promote it to result
                if (!resultList.Any() || IsBetterSolution(resultList, subResultList))
                {
                    resultList = subResultList.ToList();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return resultList;
    }

    public bool IsBetterSolution(List<List<decimal>> previousSolution, List<List<decimal>> newSolution)
    {
        //If the new solution has more pools than the previous, then it is considered better
        if (newSolution.Count > previousSolution.Count)
        {
            return true;
        }
        //If they have the same amount of pools, then choose the solution with the lowest highest sum
        return (newSolution.Count == previousSolution.Count) && (highestSum(newSolution) < highestSum(previousSolution));
    }

    public decimal highestSum(List<List<decimal>> solution)
    {
        return solution.Max(x => x.Sum());
    }

    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSet<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
               select
                   from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
                   where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
                   select list[i];
    }
```